# protractor by.repeater how to find sibling elements

Tags: protractor

I want to get the text for all the elements  where the icon has error (don't want the one with warning) with `class="dropdown-item-icon ctp-img-notification-error"`

How can I get that?

In this case I only want the text **"unable to load Data"**, since that is an error

```html
<li ng-repeat="option in options" class="dropdown-item ng-scope">
  <a href ng-class="{ selected : isSelected(option)}" ng-click="selectItem(option)">
    <div data-ng-if="option.iconCls" class=ng-scope">
      <div class="dropdown-item-icon ctp-img-notification-error" data-ng-class="options.iconCls"></div>
      <div class="ng-binding">unable to load Data</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href ng-class="{ selected : isSelected(option)}" ng-click="selectItem(option)">
    <div data-ng-if="option.iconCls" class=ng-scope">
      <div class="dropdown-item-icon ctp-img-notification-warning" data-ng-class="options.iconCls"></div>
      <div class="ng-binding">using cache Data</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought looks like this:

```js
var errorMessages = [];

element.all(by.css('.dropdown-item-icon.ctp-img-notification-error .ng-binding')).then(function(items) {
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.getText().then(function(message) {
      errorMessages.push(message);
    });
  }); 
});
```

Comment: This will give me the Error Icons div, where as i want the message div(ng-binding).

I want the message inside Div with ng-binding class, when there is also an error icon and only in those cases.

Comment: I edited my answer by adding '.ng binding' as child in the css selector. Does it work now?